# How to check if client ip is blocked by google

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We developed app based on firestore.
Some of my clients is blocked by ip. I trying to understand if google can put his ip to some black list?

Comment: More likely that the port is blocked, or an error in routing or DNS

Comment: Unless you are developing botnets, I doubt google is blocking your clients. What makes you believe that this is google's doing? Why do you think that the blocking is happening "by ip"?